# python static on call magic method

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a `Service` class that holds the `Registry` instances. The `Registry` and `Service` classes are the following;

```
class Registry:

    def __init__(self, registrar):
        self.registrar = registrar

    def get(self, key):
        layers = key.split('.')
        value = self.registrar
        for item in layers:
            value = value[item]
        return value

class Service:

    instance = None

    @classmethod
    def boot(cls, object, configuration = {}):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = object(configuration)
```

What I currently want is after the `boot` function is called, The registry functions should be accessible from `Service` class statically without defining functions in `Service` class. So, after booting with the following code, I want to use `get` function.

```
Service.boot(Config, {'a' : 'b'});
Service.get('a');
```

NOTE: Config object is an extension of Registry

I've tried `__getattr__` magic method but it doesn't work on static.
I've tried `__call__` but after that I need to call `Service().get()` which is not that I want.

So, is it possible to make this happen in python ? I don't want to redefine class methods in `Service` layer.

NOTE: In PHP, there exists `__callStatic()` function that does exactly that I want. However, I can't find an implementation on python.

Comment: "I've tried `__getattr__` magic method but it doesn't work on static" Do you really need to access via the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could slightly modify your call patterns, I could imagine that it is feasible:

```
cfg = Service.boot(Config, {'a' : 'b'})
cfg.get('a')
```

In this way, you could perfectly make it work with `__getattr__` if you make `boot()` return an object which provides these methods.

If not, you could try one of the following:

1. Just call `cfg.instance.get('a')`
2. Give `Service` a metaclass:

   ```
   class Registry:

       def __init__(self, registrar):
           self.registrar = registrar

       def get(self, key):
           layers = key.split('.')
           value = self.registrar
           for item in layers:
               value = value[item]
           return value

   class DeflectToInstance(type):
       def __getattr__(selfcls, a): # selfcls in order to make clear it is a class object (as we are a metaclass)
           try:
               # first, inquiry the class itself
               return super(Meta, selfcls).__getattr__(a)
           except AttributeError:
               # Not found, so try to inquiry the instance attribute:
               return getattr(selfcls.instance, a)

   class Service:
       __metaclass__ = DeflectToInstance
       instance = None

       @classmethod
       def boot(cls, NewCls, configuration={}):
           if cls.instance is None:
               cls.instance = NewCls(configuration)

   Service.boot(Registry, {'a': 'b'})
   print Service.get('a')
   ```

   Here the metaclass provides an appropriate way to deflect attribute accesses to the class to one of its attributes.

   Be aware that under Py3, the syntax is slightly different. IIRC, it is

   ```
   class Service(metaclass=DeflectToInstance):
   ```

---

(However, it seems slightly wrong to me to use the `Service` class just for this kind of encapsulation.

You can do this `cfg = boot(...)` from my first idea at one place and subsequently use `cfg` for every access. You might even (misleadingly) name it `Config`:

```
class Registry:

    def __init__(self, registrar):
        self.registrar = registrar

    def get(self, key):
        layers = key.split('.')
        value = self.registrar
        for item in layers:
            value = value[item]
        return value

cfg = Registry(...)
```

or

```
Config = Registry(...)
```

and subsequently use `cfg` (or `Config`) everywhere you want.)

Comment: the problem here is it is needed to call `Service.boot()` every time so that we can get an instance on config object. However, what I want is services should be booted once and should be accessible everywhere while server/program is running

Comment: @aacanakin If even `cfg.instance.get('a')` is not an option, then the only choice seems to be a metaclass. See my edit.

Comment: `Config` is simply a `Registry` extension that is initialized once and used in the project everywhere. `Service` is a facade that hides the complexity behind `Registry` and make it enable to use statically without instance creation which is I wanted. The name `Service` might be misleading. But it works currently. Thanks @glglgl